# ArrayList sorting, application stuck

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I have an ArrayList filled with words from a text file, that I need to sort by occurrence of words, from the most occurring to the less occurring. I copy the original ArrayList with the words to another Arraylist as well as adding on top the number of occurrences. So the word in the new ArrayList would look, for example:
"password:125" where "password" is the word and "125" is the number of occurrences in the ArrayList.

```
for (int i=0;i<sorter.size();i++) {
                    sorter2.add(sorter.get(i)+":"+Collections.frequency(sorter, sorter.get(i)));
                }
```

Afterwards I sort the ArrayList with this class:

```
public class RepeatFormulaCounter implements Comparator<String> {

    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        if (findValue(o2) != findValue(o1)) {
            return findValue(o2) - findValue(o1); 
        }
        return o2.compareTo(o1);
    }
    public int findValue(String find){
        int result=0;
        String spliter[]=find.split(":");        
        result=Integer.parseInt(spliter[1]);
        return result;
    }


}
```

However as I have 5 text files filled with words which 3 of the files are around 45 000 words and 2 with more than 1 000 000, The files with around 45000 words are sorted and displayed without any problems, but when I start to sort the ones with more than 1 000 000 words the application gets stuck. Why does it happen? and how can I fix it?

Please notice I am using a GUI application to displaying it. And I am using 2 similar sort classes for other ways of sorting by different criteria's which display and perform without any problems.

Comment: What do you display in GUI? What GUI components you are using? It is more likely problem with GUI component not being able to handle too many data points.

Comment: because sorting is not a trivial task. what algorithm do you use to sort? in any way you should make your `compare` function faster, dont call findValue() two times for both objects. Integer parsing is fairly expensive if you do it more than 10 million times.

Comment: I am displaying the top 10 most occurring words on "JTextArea" by appending the 10 words.

Comment: Ok. It is possible that program gets stuck because it is generating lot of garbage and having many GC cycles. You can check this using jconsole or jvisualvm. Atleast you will be able to determine if program is getting stuck because of cpu load or memory issues.

Comment: Thank you for your answers guys, it will take me a while to understand and try everything. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you store words as "`password:125`"? You are working in very inefficient way. You must use efficient data structure to store your word's statistics. Use Map interface and choose right implementation to store words with its occurrence.

```
Map<String, Integer> wordsMap = new HashMap<String,Double>();

/* Fill the wordsMap with data, then use this function to sort.
  Fill and update value by key is simple:

  wordsMap .put(key, 50); <-- put value
  wordsMap .put(key, map.get(key) + 1); <--- update value

  For example:

  wordsMap .put("google", 0); <-- put value
  wordsMap .put("google", map.get("google") + 1); <--- increment value by 1

*/

public static <K, V extends Comparable<? super V>> Map<K, V> 
    sortByValue( Map<K, V> map )
{
    List<Map.Entry<K, V>> list =
        new LinkedList<>( map.entrySet() );
    Collections.sort( list, new Comparator<Map.Entry<K, V>>()
    {
        @Override
        public int compare( Map.Entry<K, V> o1, Map.Entry<K, V> o2 )
        {
            return (o1.getValue()).compareTo( o2.getValue() );
        }
    } );

    Map<K, V> result = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    for (Map.Entry<K, V> entry : list)
    {
        result.put( entry.getKey(), entry.getValue() );
    }
    return result;
}

// sortByValue(wordsMap);
```

Additionally, you can read about classes `Hashtable, LinkedHashMap, TreeMap` and then choose the one with better performance. They implements the same Map interface, but has different asymptotics for internal implementation of put(), get() and other methods.

The Javadocs from Sun for each collection class will generally tell you exactly what you want.

**HashMap, for example:**

> This implementation provides constant-time performance for the basic
>   operations (get and put), assuming the hash function disperses the
>   elements properly among the buckets. Iteration over collection views
>   requires time proportional to the "capacity" of the HashMap instance
>   (the number of buckets) plus its size (the number of key-value
>   mappings).

**TreeMap:**

> This implementation provides guaranteed log(n) time cost for the
>   containsKey, get, put and remove operations.

**TreeSet:**

> This implementation provides guaranteed log(n) time cost for the basic
>   operations (add, remove and contains).

[Read more about this.](http://www.programcreek.com/2013/03/hashmap-vs-treemap-vs-hashtable-vs-linkedhashmap/)

If it will be still slower then yours expectations, you can use multithreading. If you have processor with 8 cores, you can split your file to 8 peaces, count words in 8 threads, merge results, and then run sort.

Comment: and what about the sorting part?

Comment: Thank you for your answer it set me up on the right path.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be outside of the code shown, but you could try to reduce object trashing by reducing the amount of find calls and then number of objects created (currently, each find call creates 3 new objects and you call find 4 times in compare):

```
@Override
public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
    int f2 = findValue(o2);
    int f1 = findValue(o1);
    if (f2 != f1) {
        return f2 - f1; 
    }
    return o2.compareTo(o1);
}

public int findValue(String find){
    int result = 0;
    int cut = find.lastIndexOf(':');
    result = Integer.parseInt(find.substring(cut + 1));
    return result;
}
```

This can probably be improved some more by getting rid of substring...

Probably a better option would be to hand in the map that you use for counting to the comparator constructor, and then use it in the comparator:

```
public class CountComparator implements Comparator<String> {
  Map<String, Integer> counts;
  public CountComparator(Map<String, Integer> counts) {
    this.counts = counts;
  }

  public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
    int f2 = counts.get(o2);
    int f1 = counts.get(o1);
    if (f1 != f2) {
      return f2 - f1;
    } 
    return o2.compareTo(o1);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer, it helped me in a different way as well.

Comment: You may want to upvote all the helpful answers and to accept the one that solves the problem...O:)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely a memory issue. Try increasing your jvm heap size. You make lots of temporary strings and your garbage collector will go crazy at large data sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of streams that were introduced in Java 8. They are great for processing data.

```
HashMap<String, Integer> occurences = new HashMap<>();
...
Stream<String> stream = occurences.entrySet().stream()
    .sorted((a, b) -> b.getValue() - a.getValue())
    .map(kv -> kv.getKey());
String[] sortedWords = stream.toArray(size -> new String[size]);
```

Comment: I just tested the performance of that code. Even if the HashMap contains 1 million different Strings it takes less than 1 second and consumes less than 200 MB of RAM.